# AngularJS passing data back from modal

Tags: angularjs

I'd appreciate some help here...  I am looking at making use of AngularJS for a few projects I have in mind.  Currently experimenting with the Bootstrap UI directive.  Please take a look at my code here: http://pastebin.com/zJGpNLep

Is there a way I can update $scope.groups with the data from $scope.formData which is generated from a modal?  I have tried $scope.groups.push($scope.formData) which has proved unsuccessful and only way I can see the new data is by refreshing the page.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just left out these lines:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (formData) {
  //use formData
});
```

This should go at the end of your $scope.showAddGroupModal function as shown in the bootstrap-ui example here:

```
$scope.open = function () {

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
    resolve: {
      items: function () {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
  }, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to interact with the promise in the *result* property of the object that is returned from the call to *open*.  That promise will be resolved when the modal is closed or rejected when the modal is dismissed.  Any data that you pass to *close* or *dismiss* will be returned through the promise callbacks.

At a high level, it looks like this:

```
var modal = $modal.open({
   // modal setup
});

modal.result.then(function(group) {
    $scope.groups.push(group)
}, function () {
   // the modal was dismissed
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome... This proved to be the right one for me...Many thanks! :)